# How does this link function know what "tabsCtrl" references?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reading through the AngularJS documentation when I came across this piece'o information in the section titled "Creating [Directives that Communicate](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)"... looking further at the js code for this example, we see that they pass a reference to a controller used in a different directive, but they don't explain why it works or how to properly use it (what the hay, man?).

So why does it work that way?  Would it work if my directives weren't chained together / in separate files?  How about if they're both registered to a module in different places?  This seems to be in an odd place..

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
    tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
```

Tl;DR How does it konw what tabsCtrl references???

Comment: [Dependencies Injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't explain why we can use seemingly whatever we want as a reference to the controller as long as it's at the end of the link function's params...  What if we didn't do it this way?  What if there are multiple controllers and directives NOT chained together?  Does it matter if we use $require or don't return a controller on the directive? ~:[

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the docs:

> The myPane directive has a require option with value ^myTabs. When a
>   directive uses this option, $compile will throw an error unless the
>   specified controller is found. The ^ prefix means that this directive
>   searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the
>   directive would look for the controller on just its own element).
>
> So where does this myTabs controller come from? Directives can specify
>   controllers using the unsurprisingly named controller option. As you
>   can see, the myTabs directive uses this option. Just like
>   ngController, this option attaches a controller to the template of the
>   directive.
>
> Looking back at myPane's definition, notice the last argument in its
>   link function: tabsCtrl. When a directive requires a controller, it
>   receives that controller as the fourth argument of its link function.
>   Taking advantage of this, myPane can call the addPane function of
>   myTabs.

Translating that to human language: `require: '^myTabs'` in `myPane` searches for controller in `myTabs` (well, `myTabs` should be parent directive to `myPane`) directive and passes it as fourth parameter to `link: function()` in `myPane`.

Comment: That part I understood, but it doesn't explain if it HAS to be a parent directive of the other or not, it doesn't explain why it doesn't matter what you type in as the reference.  It just works 'magically' (unless I use my magic wand to grokk the library, but I wouldn't be reading this now would I?).

Comment: No,no,no. It says that "^" means search for controller in parent directives. And it also says that if you do `require: ` controller from other directive it would be passed as the fourth parameter to `link: `. It doesn't matter how you call it. It still would be controller of `myTabs`. No magic.